# User Avatar plugin wordpress, how to display image

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using [User Avatar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-avatar/) plugin for wordpress. Now I would like display the image for user. I'm trying with this code but not found.

```
<?php 

$id = 2631;

echo get_avatar( $id, 32 ); 

?>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$id = $user id;
echo get_avatar( $id); 
?>
```